# Nginx upload PUT and POST

Tags: nginx, upload

I am trying to make nginx accept POST and PUT methods to upload files. I have compiled nginx_upload_module-2.2.0.

I can't find any how to. I simply want to use only nginx for this, no reverse proxy, no other backend and no php.

Is this achievable?

this is my conf:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.2.3TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g' --add-module=/usr/src/nginx-1.2.3/nginx_upload_module-2.2.0


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com;

    location / {
        root   /html;
        autoindex on;
    }

    location /upload {
        root    /html;
        autoindex on;
        upload_store /html/upload 1;

        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";

        upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.md5" "$upload_file_md5";
        upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";
        upload_pass_form_field "^submit$|^description$";
        upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;
    }
}
```

And as an upload form I'm trying to use the one listed at the end of this page: http://grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html

Answer (score 7):

Regarding POST requests: Maybe you didn't create the directories 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
in your upload target dir?

You can always use DAV for PUT requests, you got it compiled into your nginx already:

```
location /upload {
  alias     upload/data;
  client_body_temp_path  upload/client_tmp;

  dav_methods  PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;

  create_full_put_path   on;
  dav_access             group:rw  all:r;

}
```

And you'll need this (in http or location):

```
client_max_body_size 10000m;
```

Now have a try:

```
curl -T ubuntu-10.04.4-alternate-amd64.iso http://localhost/upload/blah2
```

Cheers!
Georg

Answer (score 1):

The third party upload module does not support PUT at all. If you want to use PUT uploads you must do so using standard nginx upload handling.

Comment: forget about the methods then. I'm just interested in how to upload.

Comment: I noticed that you gave more details on the nginx mailing list so I ended up responding there instead.